# Automatically log user out of Facebook after inactivity

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

As per FB policies, when a user logs out of my site they are logged out of FB too.

However, my sessions are destroyed after 20mins inactivity, can I somehow destroy the FB session too?

The issue is: another user goes onto the site not knowing that another user is still logged into FB, and my system trying to be a good UI logs them auto back in if it sees a FB user active.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you're using the JSSDK, there's a method to log the user out. You can call this when you're invalidating your session, assuming you can trigger some client-side code when that happens.

See https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.logout/

Comment: Thanks for this - on reflection it's a stupid idea as the user might be just away from my site and on Facebook, and all of a sudden I'd log them out - not the best UI ha ha